# Make cell stick to the bottom of a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello I am trying to figure out how can you stick the last cell/section on a tableview to the bottom screen. This is the screenshot.

[image]

I am trying to put the create account at the bottom.  I've tried using the tableview footer but this is what I get.

[image]

How would I be able to put that red view at the very bottom. I know I can just use a view controller and drag a table view controller and place the button at the bottom. However I would like to learn how to do this using the tableview controller. Would really appreciate any help :)

This is the table view footer code I am using in the viewDidLoad. Which creates the red view at the bottom of the create account.

```
let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40))
    footerView.backgroundColor = .red
    tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

Comment: Why make it as a cell? Try to use a footer

Comment: I did and I get the red view. I would like to get the red view to show at the bottom

Comment: yes I agreed with @user9335240! You can use footer view! This will stick to bottom of Tableview!

Comment: @LuisRamirez Please share the code that you have done for footer view!

Comment: @SachinDobariya Okay I have add the code I used to get the red view.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see what the issue is.

When you assign the `UITableView.tableFooterView` it puts it at the *end* of all the cells.  It's not *fixed* to the bottom of the table.

Because `UITableViewController` does not have a parent `view` outside of the `tableview`, there is no way to add a view to the tableview that will not also cover up additional cells.

For example, you could programmatically create a `UIView`, add constraints, and then add it as a subview of the `tableview` - this would likely have undefined behavior if the table view ever changes the number of rows in it. 
Even if it worked, it would likely cover up cells as you scrolled.

Unless there is some external constraint, I recommend you use the correct tool for the job - make a `UIViewController` and put a `UITableView` and your red view underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

Add your button on storyboard under of your tableview. in your case there is no reason to have it in a tableview cell

Answer (score 0):

You may use a little trick: as you know, header stick to the top of the table view. What you can do is mirror the table view and its contents horizontally by applying scale transform, like so

```
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

also, in your `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

and in `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
headerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

Just make your `Create Button` a section header and apply transforms.

Alternatively, you can simply add that button as a subview to your table view on the bottom, and provide an empty view as section footer view, with height equal to your button's height.